# iOS segmented control problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

So I have a strange problem with my segmented control I am trying to use.  Essentially I have a preferences panel that displays via a popover when a button is pushed.

The problem:  I am trying to save the state so when the view loads, the segmented control should save it's selected item.  Here is what I am doing so far...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if(!self.mainViewController.isThreaded){
    self.threadedView.selectedSegmentIndex == 0;
    //[self.threadedView setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
            //I can't do this because if I do it, it rexecutes the changeSegment method,
            // which I do not want

}
if(self.mainViewController.isThreaded){
    self.threadedView.selectedSegmentIndex == 1;
    //[self.threadedView setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
}
//threadedView.momentary = NO;
}


-(void)changeSegment {
if(self.threadedView.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    self.mainViewController.isThreaded = NO;
    [self.threadedView setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

}
if(self.threadedView.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    self.mainViewController.isThreaded = YES;
    [self.threadedView setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
}
}
```

now the problem is, when the popover appears, it does not load the state to the segmented control, as I understand it should.  Can anyone point out what I may be doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Do you retain self(ViewController) after you close it?

Comment: like when you press off the popover (ie. viewDidDisappear method?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In viewWillAppear, if you want to set them and not test them it should be:

`self.threadedView.selectedSegmentIndex = 0/1;`

not

`self.threadedView.selectedSegmentIndex == 0/1;`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: HAHAH wow, how did I not see that.... lemme test it and get back to you.  (sulks off in shame)

Comment: Actually That did not fix the problem where it is reloading. It is still firing the changeSegment method when the view appears.  Is there a better way to do this??

Comment: I figured out a workaround where I conditionally execute based on if the view is appearing or a button is being pushed.  Thanks for the help.